# Program terminating while reference the front packet in queue

Tags: multithreading, ffmpeg

I have 2 threads to decode RTSP stream video, my code as below:

```
    int key = 0;
    std::queue<AVpacket> Packet_buf;

    int thread1 (void) 
    {
           AVPacket packet;
           packet = read_packet();
           Packet_buf.push(packet);
           av_packet_unref(&packet);
           key = 1;
    }

    int thread2 (void)
    {
          AVPacket *packet;
          while(key==0) {} // wait to read the first packet
          *packet = Packet_buf.front(); // program halt here
          avcodec_send_packet(pCodecCtx,packet);
    }

    int main();
    {
         thread p1(thread1);
         thread p2(thread2);
    }
```

My program crash at line: *packet = Packet_buf.front();

Can you help me to find the problem, Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Your code have more the one issues, some of them:

**1)** `std::queue<AVpacket> Packet_buf;`

I think this would be:

`std::queue<AVPacket> Packet_buf;` notice `AVpacket` and `AVPacket` is whole different thing. (Yes, I'm guessing this just a typo).

**2)** `while(key==0) {}` This is not a good way to wait on a variable change. Especially if the variable *(key)* is not `volatile`. It may work and probably is working. But I suggest you use *pthread* `signal` and `cond`ition variables here instead. Also check next issue (3) which is closely related.

**3)** `*packet = Packet_buf.front();` Caling `std::queue.front()` before checking whether the container is `empty()` or not is NOT good idea. If container (queue) is empty than `front()` method here will result in undefined behavior.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank @the kamilz, 1) is a typing error, 2) just a fast way to transfer my idea, 3) my full code is quite long, so I just write the idea, and I make sure that the queue contain 15->20 packets before it's popped

Comment: Then it's more complicated. I'm almost sure there is a race condition going on, but this time too you'll say "my actual code is also has mutex'es guards against data races...." So... what can I say...

Comment: I just want to make it simple to easy to read (just focus on the line program halting).
I found the problem: I create a queue with AVPacket type but I try to read to a pointer AVPacket *.